# Failed to resolve firebase dependency

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

My `build.gradle` file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.my.prohead"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'

    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'

    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But it doesn't get compiled although the dependency is set up already
if i try to change the implementation it says the dependencies are not set!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Remove this from your app level `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0:15.0.0'
```

and add only this

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
```

Comment: After doing the changes it get compiled properly but the green tick for "Add firebase authentication to your app" gets removed

Comment: @AnkitPalande Don't worry for that. Firebase would work for you!

Answer (score 1):

should be:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1' //delete 15.0.0
```

in the project level build gradle file:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google() //add this line
    jcenter()
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: it compiles properly but firebase unticks the green tick on "2. Add firebase authentication to your app"